# Program returns 0 but only to "one up" in recursion, but I want it to go to the "very top"? Is this possible?

Tags: recursion, palindrome

I'm new to using recursion and I'm trying to get my palindrome program to work.  This is what I am trying to do: if a character is not equal, I return 0. If not, I keep recursing while increasing the i and decreasing the j. If the i is no longer less than the j, i want to say that the recursion is done, so I want to return that the word is a palindrome (=1).

But when I input a word that is not a palindrome, I correctly return a 0. (I can see this when I debug). But-- then at the end, it also returns a 1. I assume this has something to do with the fact that recursion means that the program keeps going, and the 0 gets returned to something I had previously been doing before. But- I want the 0 to go to the very top.

Is there some way around this problem? Or am I doing something wrong? Sorry if this is really basic. 
Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```
public static int checkIfPalindrome(String s, int i, int j) {

    if (i<j) {

        if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
            checkIfPalindrome(s, i+1, j-1);

        }
        else {
            return 0; 
        }
    }
    return 1;

}
```

Comment: You're missing a return statement for your recursive call, so you effectively throw away the results of deeper levels of the recursion and default to returning a 1.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you know your pointers haven't collided, and the characters they point to are the same, then the return value of *this* method is the return value of the recursive call.  I've fixed your code to do this below but I have also reorganized it a different way, as there are other ways to go about the problem:

```
public static int checkIfPalindrome(String s, int i, int j) {

    if (i >= j) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(j)) {
        return 0;
    }

    return checkIfPalindrome(s, i + 1, j - 1);
}
```